# Append data from google places JSON response with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am trying to append info i get from a get request using google places api javascript with jquery and im COMPLETELY lost. according to the google dev console i am sending a successful request. but i have no clue how to append the response to a div. ive looked at the sample and everything it starting to look like its written in latin.

my get request :

```
    $('#button').click(function() {
             $.ajax({
         type : 'GET',
         url : "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        success : function(data) {
//i dont know what to put here
}
});
});
```

this is an example of the response https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/

lets say i wanted to append the "formatted_address" to a div. how would i get from where im at to that point ?

Comment: This seems to be an incomplete code. It's cutting off at the bottom. You can specify `success` function in ajax call that will be fired when the call finishes successfully. Then you work the data object to populate elements in your page. Without seeing rest of the code is hard to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is assuming you have a `div` element in your HTML with `id="DivID"`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="DivID"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
   $('#button').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
             type : 'GET',
             dataType:'json',
             url : "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
             success : function(data) {

                $('#DivID').text(data.formatted_address)

             }
        });
    });
```